# × vs \times, or unicode characters vs commands in general: Which one is the better practice?

Tags: unicode

When I enter a multiplication sign, I can either use \times or use the unicode character × (U+00D7) directly. Which one should I use? How about less common things like ∞ (infinity, U+221E)? I really like entering the math symbol directly as it is more readable, but some text editors don't support unicode characters well.

Comment: As you said *but some text editors don't support unicode characters*, so use `\times`, `\infty`, `\to` and so on.